# group by and filter the result

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a file separated by pipe, i have to do a group by a field and get its sum of occurrences.

My input file looks like:

```
96472|Text1|6|A|City|Austin, TX|0123|9899|2017-02-12
96472|Text1|6|A|City|Austin, TX|0123|9899|2017-02-12
96472|Text1|6|A|City|Austin, TX|0123|9899|2017-02-12
214126|Text1|6|A|City|Austin, TX|0123|9899|2017-02-12
214126|Text1|6|A|City|Austin, TX|0123|9899|2017-02-12
214126|Text1|6|A|City|Austin, TX|0123|9899|2017-02-12
214126|Text1|6|A|City|Austin, TX|0123|9899|2017-02-12
214126|Text1|6|A|City|Austin, TX|0123|9899|2017-02-12
214126|Text1|6|A|City|Austin, TX|0123|9899|2017-02-12
214126|Text1|6|A|City|Austin, TX|0123|9899|2017-02-12
214126|Text1|6|A|City|Austin, TX|0123|9899|2017-02-12
214126|Text1|6|A|City|Austin, TX|0123|9899|2017-02-12
214126|Text1|6|A|City|Austin, TX|0123|9899|2017-02-12
```

This is how I am doing it:

```
cut -d'|' -f1 somefile.txt | cut -d'-' -f1 | sort | uniq -c 
output is 
 3 96472
 10 214126
```

Essentially I want to sum up the occurrence of a field, just like group by clause in sql. so in my example i show that field/column 1 having srepeated values as 3 and 10

I am sure there is a better way to do it. And i also want to filter records which has less the 10 occurrences i do :

```
cut -d'|' -f1 somefile.txt | cut -d'-' -f1 | sort | uniq -c | grep -v 10
```

is there a good way to achieve both?

Comment: thanks just put down the input file for test

Comment: i want to some the occurrence of a field, just like group by clause in sql. so in my example i show that f1 having same values is repeated 10 times

Comment: ok let me try clarifying it , i want to sum the occurrence of same value of a column/field. In the example, I sum the occurrence of the same value in 1st field/column. Updated the question.

Comment: updated the question

Comment: what about the possible negative numbers? since I saw `cut -d'-' -f1`, are you interested in considering abs()?

Comment: @Lino yes i am interested in abs

Comment: ok, so right now, only my answer considers absolute values

Answer (score 6):

A simple `awk` logic could be sufficient for this, than to use other utilities. For your input file in question, the output is as follows;

```
awk -F"|" '{count[$1]++}END{for (i in count) print count[i],i}' file
3 96472
10 214126
```

The idea is `count[$1]++` increments the occurrence of `$1` in the file and once the file is processed, the `END` clause prints out the total count of each of the unique fields in `$1`

Another filter to list only those count less than 10

```
awk -F"|" '{count[$1]++}END{for (i in count) if (count[i] < 10){print count[i],i}}' file
3 96472
```

Comment: great how do i display records whose count < 10. I am currently using 'grep -v' in my example.

Comment: @BhaskarMishra: Refer my update. You don't need any other tools when `awk` is there, it is so powerful!

Comment: @BhaskarMishra: Don't forget to upvote/accept the answer once you find it solving your problem

Comment: Is this the fastest way, i have a 8gb file and the results seemingly taking the same amount of time.

Comment: If `awk` doesn't make it fast, no other tool will

Comment: @BhaskarMishra: And how fast was it?

Answer (score 0):

Just an answer that extends your command:

```
cut -d'|' -f1 somefile.txt | cut -d'-' -f2 | sort | uniq -c | awk '{ if ($1 < 10) print $0  }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you data is in file `txt`.

`sort -t '|' -k 1 txt | uniq -c | awk -F"|" '{print $1}' | awk '{if($1 < 10) print $0}'`

`sort` command will:

- tokenize (`-t '|'`) the data on `'|'` character and then
- choose the first token (`-k 1`) for sorting